# Text extraction using RUTA scripts- Before and After conditions

Tags: ruta

I need to extract text which is between 2 keywords eg: Full Name XYZ123 Middle Name and I need . How to achieve this using `BEFORE` and `AFTER` conditions in RUTA script?

Tried something like below, but didn't work.

```
W{AFTER(W{ REGEXP("(?i)(Full)")}
        W{ REGEXP("(?i)(Name)")})};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask], then [edit] your question to explain *what* did not work. Are the results incorrect, do you get an error message, does your computer explode ...? See [mcve] on what's required for debugging questions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating annotations for "Full Name" and for "Middle Name" and use a sequential pattern instead of the BEFORE/AFTER condition:

DECALRE FullName, MiddleName;
"Full Name"->FullName;
"Middle Name"->MiddleName;
FullName #{->MyType} MiddleName;
...or...
FullName ANY[0,5]{-PARTOF(MiddleName)->MyType} MiddleName;

I peronsally would recommend not to use these two conditions as there are always better solutions. If you do not want to specify new types and annotations, you could use literal string matching like:

`"Full Name" #{->MyType} "Middle Name";`